# Match words with double letters

Tags: java, regex

I am using

```
^(?i)(?=.*\bWORD_TO_MATCH\b).*$
```

I need to match also words with double letters...
for example:

"Matthew Jonson" matches with

```
^(?i)(?=.*\bmatthew\b)(?=.*\bjonson\b).*$
```

but "Mathew Jonson" doesn't

Another example:

ABA should match (regex\ABA\) and (regex\ABBA\)

How can I make the regex "double letters insensitive"?

Comment: Something like `m+a+t+h+e+w+`?

Comment: @tobias_k elaborate, please...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. I suggest you edit the question to show some strings that you do want to match, some you don't, and what the essential difference is. Also add a tag to specify what language you're using.

Comment: Putting a `+` behind each character means that each character has to appear one or more times. If you want to allow one or two times, you could also use `{1,2}`, but I don't think there's a flag or another builtin way for either. Best thing you could do is write a helper function to automatically insert those quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [back reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

```
(.)\1
```

`(.)` captures one of *any character* into capturing group `1`. `\1` matches if the previous match appears again.

If you don't care about *any char* but letters use:

```
([A-Za-z])\1
```

The final regex to find words with double letters in them should look like this:

```
\b.*([A-Za-z])\1.*\b
```

You can test it online: http://fiddle.re/u4ar46

Comment: Could you please apply it to my previous regex?
^(?i)(?=.*\bWORD_TO_MATCH\b).*$

Comment: Sorry I didn't got your question properly an my first attempt to answer. Is WORD_TO_MATCH a static term?

Comment: no, it's dynamic. 
I simply need to match names with double letters.
example: i need to match both MAT and MATT

Comment: Then use `\b.*([A-Za-z])\1.*\b`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is itertools.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby("Matthew Jonson"))
'Mathew Jonson'
```

Comment: Could you please apply it to my previous regex?
^(?i)(?=.*\bWORD_TO_MATCH\b).*$

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no builtin way to do this with regex. You could, however, put a `+` behind each character in the word to allow one *or more* instances of that character.

You could write a helper function to automatically insert those quantifiers.

Here's an example in Python, but you can do the same in Java:

```
>>> import re
>>> names = "Mathew Jonson Matthew Jonson Matthew Johnson"
>>> name = "mathew jonson"
>>> "(?i)" + "+".join(name) + "+"
'(?i)m+a+t+h+e+w+ +j+o+n+s+o+n+'
>>> re.findall("(?i)" + "+".join(name) + "+", names)
['Mathew Jonson', 'Matthew Jonson']
```

If you want to allow only one or two instances of the character, you could do the same with `{1,2}` instead of `+`.